# Settng the schema of a Hibernate entity extra to the default schema configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration

I have a Hibernate / Spring 4 application, where the default schema of the entity classes is already configured, e.g. they end up mapped as `testschema.table` or `prodschema.table`.

However there is another entity class which needs its own configurable schema, e.g. only this entity must be mapped to `testschema2.anothertable` or `prodschema2.anothertable`.

Nice would be something like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="anothertable", schema = "${db.AntherEntitySchema}") 
public class AnotherEntity {
  // ..
}
```

where the schema gets injected from the properties file, but such a feature seems only to work with the `@Value` annotation.
Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by this applicationContextPersistence.ctx.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
              value="classpath:META-INF/persistence-${env}.xml" />
    <!-- .. -->
</bean>
```

where Spring can substitute the ${} expression from a property file.

We then have a persistence-dev.xml etc which features a specific orm-dev.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="fooUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-dev.xml</mapping-file>
    </persistence-unit>
    <!-- .. -->
</persistence>
```

The orm-dev.xml is now responsible for the entity mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm    
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <description> XML Mapping file</description>

    <package>foo.server.model</package>

    <entity class="AnotherEntity">
        <table schema="testschema2" name="anothertable" />
        <attributes>
           <!-- .. -->
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Finally we removed the mapping annotations from the AnotherEntity POJO, as this one is now mapped via the orm-dev.xml file. The other enitity classes kept their annotations.

Note: We use the Spring Tool Suite flavour of Eclipse. This IDE expects a persistence.xml, so to get rid of an error message we kept a minimal persistence.xml to not have to remember the IDE option which deactivates the validator.